# How to access (multi)index of a Data Frame?

Tags: indexing, group-by, pandas

I have a data frame and use some of its columns to `group by`:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])
```

Now I use `mean` function to get a new data frame object from the above created groupby object:

```
df_new = grouped.mean()
```

Now I have two data frames (`df` and `df2`) and I would like to merge them using `col1` and `col2`. The problem that I have now is that `df2` does no have these columns. After `groupby` operation `col1` and `col2` are "shifted" to index. So, to resolve this problem, I try to create these columns:

```
df2['col1'] = df2['index'][0]
df2['col2'] = df2['index'][1]
```

But it does not work because 'index' is not recognized as a column of the data frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative Andy Hayden's method, you could use `as_index=False` to preserve the columns as columns rather than indices:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'], as_index=False).mean()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `left_index` (or `right_index`) arguments of [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

> `left_index` : boolean, default False
>             Use the index from the left DataFrame as the join key(s).
>         
>       If it is a MultiIndex, the number of keys in the other DataFrame (either the index
>       or a number of columns) must match the number of levels

and use `right_on` to determine which columns it should merge the index with.

So it'll be something like:

```
pd.merge(df, df_new, left_on=['col1', 'col2'], right_index=True)
```